# Django gets 'None' from POST-request

Tags: django, post, fetch

I sending info by fetch to my django server, but django gets **None** instead of values in the object

POST-request

```
GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;
  fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/computerAnswer/`,{
    method:'POST',
    body:JSON.stringify({value: 'value', deleted:[], answer:'computerAnswer'})
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json.msg);
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("now is " + error);
  });
```

Views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def computer_answer(request):
    print(request.POST.get('value'))
    print(request.POST.get('deleted'))
    print(request.POST.get('answer'))
    data = {'msg': ''}
    value = 0
    deleted_cities = 0
    answer_of_computer = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = request.POST.get('value')
        deleted_cities = request.POST.get('deleted')
        answer_of_computer = request.POST.get('answer')
    if value == '' or value is None:
        data['msg'] = '-1'
        return JsonResponse(data)
    data['msg'] = citiesGame.game(value, deleted_cities, answer_of_computer)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

when print is triggrerd, the None is printed.

This request goes from app on React-native.
The views.py works for sure if you make a request from host on which the real backend is located, but from the application it doesn't work(as in "about:blank" chrome)

Answer (score 2):

unlike the AJAX, fetch works differently. Need to use this

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import json
        post_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        value = post_data.get('value')
        deleted_cities = post_data.get('deleted')
        answer_of_computer = post_data.get('answer')
```

instead of this

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = request.POST.get('value')
        deleted_cities = request.POST.get('deleted')
        answer_of_computer = request.POST.get('answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You simple try

```
 if request.method == "POST":
   value = request.POST['value']
   deleted = request.POST['deleted']
   answer = request.POST['answer']
```